# Facebook API - get height of photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

When I get a pohot like that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?type=normal
```

So I get a photo, but when I put in to my page, so some photos are higher or smaller. So how I found their height? And after with JS give to photo his height.
I give this pohot in div to my page like this:

```
var photoFromFacebook = $("<div class="photo"></div>");
photoFromFacebook.css("background-image","url(https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?type=normal)");
```

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that in JavaScript, for example:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { // wait till to image is loaded
  console.log("width: "+ this.width); // the width
  console.log("height: "+ this.height); // the height
}
img.src = 'https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?type=normal';
```

Comment: Thank you, and now I try give a element height same like have the photo.

var photo = $("<div class="img"></div>");
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    photo.height(this.height);
                };
                img.src="https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?type=normal";
But doesn work.

Answer (score 0):

And I need that pohotoFromFacebook set a heihgt, which I get.

```
var photoFromFacebook = $("<div class="photo"></div>");
```